# Blender to Papermodel?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm trying to make papermodels out of my Blender projects. Google's only remotely useful result was the program Papakura, which I cannot get because I have Linux. I'm not able to run it with WINE. I want to be able to print my unwraped mesh (UV map) in a way so I can make a paper model. Is Blender capable doing this?